# D3.js loading local data file from file:///

Tags: d3.js

I know that D3.js supports loading data files with XHR and JSONP [requests](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests).

However in my case, I am going to run .html files by double clicking on them from filesystem, which is going to run it like `file://.../foo.html` on browser.

Is it possible to load data file (csv or json) within the same directory from computer as `foo.html` on browser (while not running on `http://` but `file://`)?

Comment: Firefox works fine with local filesystem. IE and Chrome do not, and the other answers have pointed out how to deal with those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can by disabling the respective security mechanisms in your browser. I think it works in Opera by default, and you can start Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` command line flag to allow loading data from `file://`.

Answer (score 30):

The best solution would be to run a server on your computer to make it work.

The simplest way to have a local web server, as explained [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#using) is to run this command in the directory where you have your source code:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

Then just load the page `http://localhost:8888`

Comment: Note: This command starts the Python web server in the background. To stop the server, type `fg` (to bring the process into the "foreground"), then press Ctrl+C. More info: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes

Comment: For Jetbrain users, right click on html file and click "Run '{filename}'" button and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto Christopher Chiche's answer (I am a new user, can't comment).
For python 3 in Windows, that command does not work. Instead use this one

```
python -m http.server [<portNo>]
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351016/set-up-python-simplehttpserver-on-windows/17351115#17351115), in python 3

> the module SimpleHTTPServer has been replaced by http.server, at least in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the python answer from Christopher Chiche above, you can also use the built-in server that comes with various versions of PHP.

```
php -S localhost:8888 &
```

This was more useful for me, as my application has hooks to a php back-end script as well as the d3 front-end.