# Set up Python simpleHTTPserver on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, simplehttpserver

I want to set up Python `SimpleHTTPServer` on Windows XP. I have Python installed on my computer. I am executing the following command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
```

But I am getting the error:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe: No module named SimpleHTTPServer
```

Is `SimpleHTTPServer` for Python available on Windows? If yes, what do I do to set up the server?

Comment: The module is called `SimpleHTTPServer`, with a capital S on Server.

Comment: same result with capital S also

Answer (score 652, accepted):

From Stack Overflow question *[What is the Python 3 equivalent of "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943751/what-is-the-python3-equivalent-of-python-m-simplehttpserver)*:

`SimpleHTTPServer` is for `python2`, so you're getting the error.

In `python3`, The following works:

```
python -m http.server [<portNo>]
```

Because using **Python 3**, the module `SimpleHTTPServer` has been replaced by `http.server`, at least in Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful. With python33 the command `python -m http.server 7777` works perfectly.

Comment: Windows 7 , using Anaconda python, this worked great; $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7070

Comment: I can confirm $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer works under Windows 7 Python installed with cygwin

Comment: that's marvelous! even in windows i can do things with only 1 line in console.  Bravo!

Comment: For the network novices (myself included), who use Windows, you'll want to open the port to allow connections from other computers:  [How to open firewall ports in Windows 10](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-3114787/open-firewall-ports-windows.html)

Comment: Works for me too!

Comment: Confirming that this works for Python 3.6.7 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ! Thanks