# Can I use a local file with X.mesh?

Tags: javascript, xtk

I'm adapting Lesson 5 from [here](https://github.com/xtk/X#readme), which takes a skull vtk object and displays it rotating in a circle.  I want to change it so instead of accessing the `.vtk` object at `http://x.babymri.org/?skull.vtk`, it reads from a local file.  Is this possible?  I downloaded an exact copy of the skull.vtk and tried things like `skull.file = file:///C:/Users/myName/Desktop/XTKtest/downloadedSkull.vtk;`, but I didn't get anywhere.  Is there an alternate way to do this?

Thanks in advance, I am super new to XTK and JavaScript in general...

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some code?

I think the easiest is to run a local server on your machine:

[Set up Python simpleHTTPserver on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351016/set-up-python-simplehttpserver-on-windows)

If your project directory contains the following files:

```
Project
    index.html
    file.vtk
```

1- Go inside the directory
2- Start the local server from there.
3- Make sure you can access the file through: localhost:/file.vtk
4- In you JS code, change the reference to the model to: localhost:/file.vtk

5- Go to: localhost

Et voila!

make sure to replace  by the actual port you are using for the local server, ie. localhost:8000

My 2 cts

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  I created a localhost on port 8000, and when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I can see all my files.  However, when I try to access the .vtk file my server crashes.  My terminal says `Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1',63216)`, then gives several more Tracebacks.  The line causing the crash is `skull.file = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/downloadedSkull.vtk';`.  I'm wondering if .vtk files don't like this setup. If I type the address of a jpg in the browser it displays the pic, but if I do it to the .vtk file it tries to download it...

Comment: hmmm... what are the permissions of this file? are they the same for the jpg and for the vtk file?

Comment: They seem to be the same, both file grant full control (Modify, Read & execute, Read, Write) to SYSTEM, MyUser, and Administrators.

Comment: so both have same permissions and are located in the same directory... ?

Comment: That's correct. The only differences I can see are file type and size.

Answer (score -1):

The easyest / lazyest way to do that :

1-Copy downloadedSkull.nrrd and downloadedSkull.vtk in the root directory (with index.html)

2- skull.file = 'downloadedSkull.vtk';

3-Use Firefox rather than Chrome : Firefox accept to open local file, chrome need a local server

Comment: You should cite where to download them from.