# jQuery blatantly ignoring the path I give to .getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script, `TemplateLoader.js` which loads 2 Mustache templates, and renders them on the page (or at least that's the goal).

My directory structure:

```
COMP266
    Unit 4
        scripts
            mustache.min.js
            TemplateLoader.js
        PageUsingTemplateLoader.html
```

Inside of `TemplateLoader` (the object), I have the following chunk to load Mustache, and render the templates:

```
$.getScript("./scripts/mustache.min.js", function() {
    $('head').html( Mustache.render(headTemplate, data) );
    $('body').html( Mustache.render(bodyTemplate, data, uniqueBodyTemplate) );
});
```

This however, yields the following error in the developer console:

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
>       (XHR): GET - http://localhost:63342/COMP266/Unit%204/mustache.min.js?_=1450903391318

Oddly, it seems to have dropped the `script` folder completely from the path.

I decided to play around, so I changed the fetch path to (duplicating the script folder):

```
./scripts/scripts/mustache.min.js
```

But this yields:

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
>   (XHR): GET - http://localhost:63342/COMP266/Unit%204/scripts/scripts/mustache.min.js?_=1450903743022

Now it's listening! Unfortunately, this is obviously the wrong path.

I have no idea how to go about debugging this. It seems like jQuery is selectively dropping the `scripts` folder. That seems ridiculous, but just to make sure, I searched through the jQuery source, and couldn't find anything that would be doing the observed filtering of the path.

It's currently local, not hosted.

Can anyone give me a hint about what's going on here?

Comment: No idea really but I'd do the following: view the source of TemplateLoader.js as delivered to the browser. I don't know what your web server is but I suspect some configuration on the server is re-writing the path; the next thing would be to simply change the name of the scripts folder to js and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: To me it looks like some kind of urlrewrite is interfering.

Comment: @bknights It's local currently, so there shouldn't be anything messing with it.

Comment: @KevinB I don't even know what that is. Is that a part of jQuery?

Comment: No, it would be server-side. think, .htaccess, or web.config.

Comment: @KevinB It's local currently, so it can't be that. I've updated the question.

Comment: what if you write "scripts/mustache.min.js"

Comment: localhost can have .htaccess and/or web.config, so it being "local" is irrelevant, unless you're working from file:///

Comment: do you really need the space in `Unit 4` folder ? Are you sure, it is not messing things up?

Comment: @ludo It looks at `http://localhost:63342/COMP266/Unit%204/mustache.min.js?_=1450905003395`

Comment: Since you are using http then there is some web server involved. I'm pretty sure IIS for instance had scripts set up as a magic folder.

Comment: @kevinB Unless WebStorm has set something up, there shouldn't be any configuration going on. I'll do a search. Thanks.

Comment: @Alp I'll trying removing the space. Edit: No change. It has the same behavior.

Comment: @bkknights This might be Webstorm doing something then.

Comment: What's your server ? Node.js ? Grunt connect? IIS ? Apache ?

Comment: @Ludo I have done nothing to set up a web server. The site will eventually be hosted on my school site, but for now, I wrote up the pages/scripts in Webstorm, then asked it to run it. I'm starting to think it's doing something.

Comment: I see, it's WebStorm's internal server. Try running a `node` server. Or a `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` server, and check if the error persists.

Comment: Ya, it's WebStorm: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/built-in-server-in-webstorm-6/. Honestly, I'm not even sure how to go about running it on another server. That's something I'll need to learn first.

Comment: If you're on OSX, go in console, `cd` to your directory where `index.html` is, and write `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`. Then go to `localhost:8080` in your browser

Comment: First just try changing the name of the scripts folder.

Comment: If you're on windows, you can always use MAMP https://www.mamp.info/en/

Comment: @Ludo I tried on Windows, but Python complains that I don't have a `SimpleHTTPServer` module. Is it an external module, or does it come with python?

Comment: @bknights Tried changing it to `js`. No change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351016/set-up-python-simplehttpserver-on-windows

Comment: Hey, try this first $.getScript("./mustache.min.js

Comment: @Ludo Thanks for the link. I got a Python server going, and got the same error (`http://localhost:8080/mustache.min.js?_=1450906896119`). For your second comment, error again (`http://localhost:63342/COMP266/Unit%204/mustache.min.js?_=1450906958237`)

Comment: that's extremely weird

Comment: Maybe the space in Unit%20;4  should be removed ?

Comment: @Ludo Already tried that. Alp suggested that above. I'm now using `js`. The weird thing is, if I point to `scripts`, it will attempt to load it (although the folder doesn't exist since the rename), but if I then point back to `js`, it drops that folder from the path. It's like something is dropping any folder that contain scripts.

Comment: Maybe you have weird permissions on that folder

Comment: @Ludo It was read-only. I changed that, and nothing happened.

Comment: Try to re-create the folder, then create the files anew, and copy/paste the content of your js files in the new ones. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: @Ludo I'll try that in a sec. I found something weird though. In the Python server console, after reloading the page, I got the following 2 lines: `127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2015 14:56:11] "GET /js/mustache.min.js?_=1450907771020 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2015 14:56:11] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2015 14:56:11] "GET /mustache.min.js?_=1450907771021 HTTP/1.1" 404 -` It looks like it's requesting the file twice, once with bad address, and once with the valid address.

Comment: Sometimes servers will look up multiple routes to find a file.

Comment: @Ludo HOLY. Ok, I solved it. It turns out I'm a complete idiot. I don't know why this caused it exactly, but it did. I'll add an answer.

Comment: @Ludo Sorry to waste your time. I feel so stupid now.

Comment: Don't worry. You know how programming is, and that DUH at the end :-)

Comment: @Ludo Very true. Thanks for your help. At the very least, I learned how to start a server using Python lol.

Comment: Hey and If you feel stupid now, means you're smarter than then ;-)

Comment: @Ludo Ha! I like the way you think. That's a good twist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was caused by me forgetting that my template added the mustache script (from a previous test), resulting in it being added twice.

I don't understand how this affected it though. It's not like the jQuery addition was succeeding while the template addition was causing the error, since changing the jQuery fetch path caused a direct change in the error message.

Sure enough though, when I removed the script import from the template, it worked.

I really don't understand how this caused a specific folder to be dropped from the path though.