# Python Pyaudio -- How to play a file streamed via HTTP

Tags: python, audio, mp3, audio-streaming, pyaudio

I am trying to figure out how to play an mp3 that exists on my server served through HTTP.  I tried to figure out pyglet but there were too many issues with AVBin to make that work (something about dividing by zero in the source code).  So, I decided to try PyAudio, but I can't figure out how to stream an mp3 source from HTTP with it.  All the examples are wav files and I need examples rather than the docs or I'm afraid I'll have to figure out the particulars of how audio works on the lowest level.  All the documentation is confusing for those of us that don't know the lingo (sample rate, etc).  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

What is your source  and target server environments? [ windows / linux / mac? ]. Also are your trying to play an audio file or video?

In either case you can use  [Gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/) with python.  I've windows laptop, so I tried with Gstreamer 1.0.x from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.0.7/)

Online examples are for Gstreamer 0.10 that  does not work with newer Gstreamer 1.0. There  lots of modifications  that are platform specific.
However, on windows  Gstreamer comes with gst-launch binary which works off the shelf. [ For Linux   there is equivalent binary ]

## Setup

### Server Side:

On server side, you need to setup HTTP server. Without knowing specifics of your environment I can say that there are various solutions available , including python http server `SimpleHTTPServer`.
See solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351016/set-up-python-simplehttpserver-on-windows)

### Client Side :

Once http server is installed  and running, on your laptop, you can simply run
`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gnome> .\gst-launch.exe playbin uri = http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/148/1482641337920-lq.mp3`

Replace http server address with your server address and port.

You can call gst-launch in your python script and go creative with it.

### OutPut:

I've opened audio files from freesound.org successfully. It should open a  audio file being served from your http server as well.

[image]