# Stream Soundcard Audio using Python Simplehttpserver

Tags: python, audio, stream, simplehttpserver

I am trying to add some basic audio streaming to a python program, I've trawled the web but not made any progress and would like some tips.

The python program currently reads serial data from a radio, converts it to json and serves it using simplehttpserver on port 8000, an html page displays all the data using a mix of html and jquery, I didn't write this and I'm a python noob btw..

I would like to stream the sound from the radio which is connected to the soundcard input to the web browser that is displaying the data, is it possible to stream the audio from the soundcard using simplehttpserver and listen to it in the browser?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but check my answer at this stackoverflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388741/python-pyaudio-how-to-play-a-file-streamed-via-http/35704638#35704638