# Python cgi server module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

When I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` or `python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000` in cmd, I get this error :

> No module named SimpleHTTPServer

or

> No module named CGIHTTPServer

Does anyone know why this happens or another way to test python cgi-scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not how you start those from the command line.

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server): the basic HTTP server is started with

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

and the CGI server with

```
python -m http.server --cgi 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Fom [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351016/set-up-python-simplehttpserver-on-windows) answer:

```
python -m http.server [<portNo>]
```