# Routing is not working with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

As a part of learning process, I am roaming around angular js routing concepts. For this, I created one inner folder inside app with two sample test html pages ..

When i run the app it should load first page from that folder but it does not not happening .. I am not sure where i have done wrong in this code...

I am getting error like this  **'angular.js:4640Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]'**

Below is my controller code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);   
   myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'Pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'Pages/second.html',
        controller: 'secondController'
    })
   });

   myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$log', function($scope,$log) {   
}]);
    myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope','$log', function($scope,$log) {   
}]);
```

and html code goes here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Learn and Understand AngularJS</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            html, body, input, select, textarea
            {
                font-size: 1.05em;
            }
        </style>

        <!-- load angular via CDN -->
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/second"><i></i>second</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and for main.html

```
   <h1>this is main page</h1>
```

and for second.html

```
    <h1>this is second page</h1>
```

Would any one please help on this query,

many thanks in advance..

Comment: which module is it complaining about in the error message?

Comment: Try removing the `/` in `<li><a href="#/second"><i></i>second</a></li>` so it would look like: `<li><a href="#second"><i></i>second</a></li>`.

Comment: You've declared the controller twice too, assume that's a typo though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things seem to be working fine for me. See the working example below:

(Just change the `href` of Home link to `#/`)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'Pages/main.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
    })

  .when('/second', {
    templateUrl: 'Pages/second.html',
    controller: 'secondController'
  })
});

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log',
  function($scope, $log) {}
]);
myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$log',
  function($scope, $log) {}
]);
```

```css
html,
body,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-size: 1.05em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- load angular via CDN -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#/second"><i></i>second</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>

  <script id="Pages/main.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <h1>this is main page</h1>
  </script>

  <script id="Pages/second.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <h1>this is second page</h1>
  </script>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Don't directly serve your Angular code using `file:///` protocol. It will not be able to make request to load resources. Use any simple lightweight servers, for example:

1. Python Simple server for Linux based platforms (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`)
2. [Mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose) for Windows

Comment: I am getting this error 'Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, '

Comment: Are you directly browsing your HTML pages by double-clicking your page i.e. which starts with `file:///`?

Comment: If yes, then on Linux based platforms, use a comment `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in your project directory and browse to `localhost:8000`

Comment: I am using windows platform ..in that case also do i need to follow above step

Comment: Then use [mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose) to serve your static files. It is a lightweight HTTP server. Angular will not able to run if you directly browse the files.

Comment: I just installed mongoose server in my windows .. how to use that one to host these static files.. could you please point me in right direction ...

Comment: It's been while I used mongoose server on Windows but you can browse to your project directly and launch mongoose from there.

Comment: Or you can try an alternative like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351016/set-up-python-simplehttpserver-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
```

with

```
<li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
```

and it should work fine. i checked.

That error means angular could not find the module you're referring to. is your script able to connect to internet and can you make sure the angular cdn is not blocked by your firewall?

you could try to download the angular-route file and reference in your html and see if it works.