# Service Worker Registration Failed

Tags: javascript, browser, service-worker, web-push

I am currently working on service worker to handle push notification in browser. Currently I am having this "SW registration failed error":

> SW registration failed with error SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin ('null') is not supported.

Check `client1.html` and `service-worker.js` file below:

**service-worker.js**

```js
console.log('Started', self);
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log('Installed', event);
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Activated', event);
});
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push message received', event);
});
```

**client1.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Client 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        // Register service worker
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(reg){
          console.log("SW registration succeeded. Scope is "+reg.scope);
        }).catch(function(err){
          console.error("SW registration failed with error "+err);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: The 1st argument to `ServiceWorkerContainer.register` is an URL.  The error message indicates that your browser is refusing to use a resource because the origin is null - which happens often for local (file://) resources.  `service-worker.js` is local - I'll bet this is why you're getting the cross origin resource issue

Comment: I do not see any reference to Pusher in the code. Why does this question have the [`pusher`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pusher) tag?

Comment: I am working on web pusher. This question came while creating web pusher. Do you have any idea how to identify unique browser to push from pusher? I am stuck in that portion.

Comment: Service worker will work only if you run it on a server.
Just by opening the index.html from the finder will not work.

You can use python -m SimpleHTTPServer or any to get started.

Comment: I'm seeing this error frequently after deploying a signed exchange (SXG). Is it possible an SXG is reporting the wrong URL and refusing to install?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Solved:**
First thing is service worker only works in secure mode either in https or localhost.
It doesnot work in local resources like file:// or http.

and second issue was during registration.

```
navigator.serviceWorkerContainer
      .register('service-worker.js')
      .then(function(reg){
```

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features

According to this doc, it should be supported:

“Secure origins” are origins that match at least one of the following (scheme, host, port) patterns:

(https, *, *)
(wss, *, *)
(*, localhost, *)
(*, 127/8, *)
(*, ::1/128, *)
(file, *, —)
(chrome-extension, *, —)

Comment: There is no navigator.serviceWorkerContainer. The syntax is ServiceWorkerContainer.register

Comment: @saugat-bhattarai You say 'second issue was during registration'. I assume you mean one should use serviceWorkerContainer instead of navigator.serviceWorker?  
  
If so:  
Docs say navigator.serviceWorker contains the value serviceWorkerContainer. So what's the issue you see there?  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/serviceWorker

Answer (score 3):

Use chrome webserver, to run the app or just a simple command in terminal would do.

```
python -m http.server <port_number>
```

Old Python 2 command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer <port_number>
```

Answer (score 3):

A weird bug in my case as this all happened without any error on my side. Simply **restarting Google chrome** fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Please register sw.js in your html page

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/myproject/scripts/common/pushNotifications/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
                     }, function(err) {
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
                });
                
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3, `SimpleHTTPServer` is NOT available. It is replaced by http.server

For more details, see:
[Set up Python simpleHTTPserver on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351016/set-up-python-simplehttpserver-on-windows)

or my note, available at:
http://t.csdn.cn/ALcS6

Comment: It doesn’t answer at all the question