# Error with Service Worker registration

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to register a service worker but I have the following error:

> Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL Protocol of the current
>   origin ('null') is not supported

I'm under localhost with node js and I have my *index.html* and *service-worker.js* in the same folder

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>TryService</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  PROVA SITO CON SERVICE WORKER
  <script>
     if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        // Register service worker
         navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(reg){
            console.log("Registration OK!. Scope is "+reg.scope);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.error("Registration FAILED! "+err);
        });
    }
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

service-worker.js

```
console.log('Started', self);
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log('Installed', event);
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
console.log('Activated', event);
});
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push message received', event);
});
```

How can I fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service worker registration failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136625/service-worker-registration-failed)

Comment: You need to run the code from a TLS-enabled (https) web server, not from the file system—even when just testing

Comment: @teeyo that question did not solved my problem.

Comment: What @sideshowbarker said. I do my testing in chrome and launch it through command line `chrome.exe --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://localhost/’` see if that works

Comment: @stef52 thank you for the tip! I'll try!