# Registering Service Worker in Codova Android platform

Tags: android, cordova, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA. I have wrapped the application as cordova application. But I see that Service worker is not getting registered. I get error "ServiceWorker registration failed: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin ('file://') is not supported."

I can see there are a few plugins for IOS that helps in registering the Service Worker. Is there a way to register the service worker in Android platform?

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136625/service-worker-registration-failed), service worker only works in secure mode either in https or localhost. It doesn't work in local resources like `file://` or `http`.

> The error message indicates that your browser is refusing to use a resource because the origin is null - which happens often for local (file://) resources. `service-worker.js` is local - I'll bet this is why you're getting the cross origin resource issue

Comment: Your are totally correct!  I used [cordova-plugin-ionic-webview](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) to set the scheme to **https** and I was able to register a service worker!

Comment: @KenCorbettJr error Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost/') with script ('https://localhost/sw.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost/') with script ('https://localhost/sw.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script. TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost/') with script ('https://localhost/sw.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.

Comment: @KenCorbettJr do you have any idea ?