# Failing to register web worker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to register a simple web worker it's failing everytime.
The console sends this error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin ('null') is not supported.

This is my JS code at a file named "index.js":

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js').then(reg => console.log("Succeed"))
};
```

**woker.js** and **index.js** are in the same folder, and **index.js** is the file that is linked to the HTML file.
Iv'e been trying to follow every guide on youtube and looked for every guide on google and still no one solved my problem...

Comment: Is your file named ```worker.js``` or ```worker.js```?

Comment: This issue was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39136817/11854340

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service Worker Registration Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136625/service-worker-registration-failed)