# How do I write (flutter web) code so JavaScript files will run on my local machine?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I built a simple flutter web app. It works fine on github.io and also on the `localhost` server:

```
$ flutter run -d chrome
```

If I create a release build:

```
$ flutter build web
```

turning the app into (basically) a JavaScript file (`main.dart.js`), why can't I just run the app by loading the created `index.html` file?

The JavaScript debugger in my browser tells me this code:

```
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
```

produces the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ServiceWorkerContainer.register: Script URL's scheme is not 'http' or 'https'
```

I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it. I know it's not as simple as just adding `http` in front of `flutter_service_worker.js`.

Comment: What is the path to the service worker js file?

Comment: @Ameer It's in the same directory as index.html.

Comment: Try putting "./flutter_service_worker.js" and see if that fixes it

Comment: Sadly, no. Thanks for responding, though.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136625/service-worker-registration-failed. Service workers can't be opened locally, they have to be opened via http or https I believe

Comment: I bet you're right. If you write this up as a response I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are opening the index.html file locally via the `file` protocol. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136625/service-worker-registration-failed) SO answer, service workers need to be opened through an `http` or `https` protocol. That's why the index.html file is working on your localserver and github.io but not when you just open it via chrome or another browser.