# Is it possible to run flutter web application without server (directly from the disk)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I've builded my flutter web application and now I try to launch it directly by double-clicking the index.html inside build/web.

But the page is blank. Is it possible to run the app without a server ? If else, I don't understand why.

**EDIT**

I've found that inside index.html, there's the `<base href="/">` tag. So I've adapted consequently. Now things are changed : favicon is correctly displayed and when I open source code of the html, I can click the link and they open correctly.

[image]

But the page remain blank

**EDIT**

I think the problem is here (see below). So is there a way to execute a flutter web app on file protocol ? I think with node.js surely.

[image]

Comment: The answer is in this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640237/how-do-i-write-flutter-web-code-so-javascript-files-will-run-on-my-local-machi

Comment: Effectively, it's not possible to run flutter app via file protocol: see this resolved question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640237/how-do-i-write-flutter-web-code-so-javascript-files-will-run-on-my-local-machi The simpliest solution is for me to use Web Server for chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)