# Google Chrome tainted canvas from local images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a vanilla JavaScript game with the html 5 canvas element, and in order to make color-based hit boxes, I need to grab image data from certain spots on the canvas. Whenever I use getImageData(), I get this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

All of the images that are being displayed on the canvas are being pulled from a local file. Is there any way that I could get this working on Chrome?

I draw the images by placing html image tags on the page and using `context.drawImage(*img id, x, y*);`

Comment: Might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972049/cross-origin-data-in-html5-canvas

Local filesystem will cause cross origin issues.  If you tried to serve it locally it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Starting your local server might be the better approach. And Chrome stays safe.

```
cd path/to/files
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Point your browser to

```
http://localhost:8000
```

[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21519302/1051251) via @gman

Comment: Or the [python 3 alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17351115/2759427): `python -m http.server [<portNo>]`

Answer (score 1):

Converting the **Image to Base64** and then use it image tags, that will solve it without changing any security settings

Answer (score 0):

It is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). You can start chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` for development purposes and later load the files from the same server the site is being hosted on, so that there is no problem. Note that this flag changes the security settings of chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972049/cross-origin-data-in-html5-canvas
answered here as well