# Load local .csv with js and process it with d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I stuck on the following thing.
I don't have a running local http-service so I'd like to handle my file loading otherwise.

First I created the following function, as suggested in some references.

```
var fileArray = [];
function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files;
        window.array = []
        if (f) {
            var r = new FileReader();
                r.onload = function(e) { 
                var contents = e.target.result;
                window.array.push(contents);
                fileArray.push({name:f.name, contents: contents});
                }
                r.readAsText(f);
                console.log(fileArray);
                } else { 
                    alert("Failed to load file");
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

Then I try to call the fileArray in a d3.csv function. But this is where I stuck - the console log just shows an empty array.

```
var dataset = []
                    d3.csv(fileArray, function(data) {
                    dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [ d["TEXT"], +d["HOURS"], +d["MONTH_DIGIT"] ]; });
                    console.log(dataset)
                });
```

The .csv file has the following structure.

```
"TEXT","HOURS","MONTH_DIGIT"
"Adjustments work",849.45,"01"
```

How do I exactly call the file to work with d3.js?

Comment: Have you tried by just passing a URL to `d3.csv()`?

Comment: That would me my last try. I'd like to take the file and it's contents and work with it.

Comment: But couldn't you just work on the file's content inside `d3.csv()`? Nothing prevents you from doing non-d3.js logic inside the cdv() method.

Comment: Can you please explain your approach further?

Comment: It seems, that my fileArray code isn't working as it should. 
I added another console.log for (f) - the file is displayed but the log for the fileArray is emtpy as it is. Anyone an idea why?

edit: started the whole thing now via python simplehttp

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3.js loading local data file from file:///](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417437/d3-js-loading-local-data-file-from-file)

Comment: See here another thread about importing csv:  files.https://stackoverflow.com/a/63871971/13730780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "take the file and it's contents and work with it", you could load the file inside the `d3.csv()` method, after the callback and the apply the changes you wanted to make to the content.

```
d3.csv('/path/to/myfile.csv, function(data) {
    // Modify the files data
    ...
    // Do something with d3.js
});
```

Comment: this would be possible if i ran a http service, which I don't have at the moment.
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:</path/to/myfile.csv>. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."
I even thought of starting a python simplehttp server but shouldn't it be possible to handle files locally without having any kind of http in the background?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with a relative path aswell as directly in the directory where the .html file is.

Comment: same problem here aswell

Comment: I also tried accessing local file through file://<path to my local file>. It fails with the error : "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.". I was not looking to update my browser settings to allow cross origin requests. Easiest way was to make the local file accessible over http.

Comment: Simple but unsafe way is to start Chrome with command and arg: C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files for Windows and open -a "Google Chrome" -n --args --allow-file-access-from-files for macOS.

Answer (score 2):

For JSON:

```
var data = JSON.parse(JavascriptStringVariableThatContainsJSON);
```

For CSV:

```
 var data = d3.csv.parseRows(JavascriptStringVariableThatContainsMyCSVdata);
```

//then add data to the graph and call enter, something like:

```
 var dataEnter = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter();
```

Answer (score 1):

`d3.csv` tries to fetch over http/https.

You need to read the file first then use `d3.csvParse` on the content (in string format).

A simple example in node:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as fs from "fs";

const csv = fs.readFileSync("./data/data.csv", "utf8");
const data =d3.csvParse(csv);
console.log(data);
```