# Trying to load simple CSV file into D3 with queue.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, queue.js

I'm a newbie to web dev, and am trying to figure out how to load CSV data into D3.js, using queue.js to ensure that data is fully loaded before I execute the next step of the code (which will be drawing a chart with the data).

I have googled this endlessly, but can't seem to wrap my head around how queue.js works.

I have the following code, and can't understand why it isn't working.

```
//Create a queue. First load CSV data, then run a function on the data once fully loaded.
queue()
.defer(d3.csv, "Workbook1.csv")
.await(makeChart(mydata));


//create global variable 'mydata' to store CSV data;

var mydata = [];

//d3 CSV loading function - load data into global variable 'mydata' and convert test scores to numeric format.

d3.csv('Workbook1.csv', function(data) {

    mydata = data;
    mydata.forEach(function(d){ d['Test_Score'] = +d['Test_Score']; });
    console.log(mydata); 

});

//create function that will print my data to the console. Once I figure this out, I'll put in some d3 code to actually make the chart.

function makeChart(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log("everything ran");
 };
```

I get the following error in the console:
    "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined".

I know that the function 'makeChart' is running because I get 'everything ran' as an output. But for some reason, it doesn't pass my 'mydata' variable in.

The console.log within the d3.csv function does work correctly and outputs the correct values. But console.log(data) in the makeChart function is showing up as 'undefined' in the console.

Apologies for the simplistic question, but I'm super new to this and the examples I've found from googling haven't enabled me to solve this problem.

Thanks,

J

Comment: Is your html page is local or on server? Because if i am true, `d3.csv('XXXX.csv', function(data)...` works only if your page is on a server. A workaround is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417437/d3-js-loading-local-data-file-from-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You doing it like this:

```
queue()
.defer(d3.csv, "Workbook1.csv")
.await(makeChart(mydata));//here you are calling the function makeChart
```

Should have been like this:

```
 queue()
    .defer(d3.csv, "Workbook1.csv") 
    .await(makeChart);//only function name is needed
```

And Make chart function should be like this:

```
function makeChart(error, data) {//first param is error and not data
  console.log(data);
  console.log("everything ran");
 };
```

**EDIT**

If you have multiple urls it will be like this:

```
queue()
.defer(d3.csv, "Workbook1.csv")
.defer(d3.csv, "Workbook2.csv")
.await(makeChart);//here you are calling the function makeChart

   function makeChart(error, data1, data2) {//first param is error and not data
      console.log(data1);//workbook1
      console.log(data2);//workbook2
      console.log("everything ran");
     };
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please explain though, why an error argument is required? As a general aside, how does one know which functions need an error argument and which don't? It an error argument required on ALL javascript functions that I create?

Comment: Also, how does the computer know to pass 'mydata' variable to the makeChart function? MakeChart takes 'data' as an input, but i haven't specified that I want the input to be 'mydata'. How does it know? If I had multiple datasets being loaded, which one would it choose?

Comment: check the edit section i think it will clear all the doubts. The callback `makeChart` is called when ALL teh ajax is complete. The error is common for all if one off teh loading fails you get an error.